# Draw inverted element colors on PHP GD lib?

Tags: php, rendering, gdlib

I need to draw for example imagefilledrectangle() in a way that every pixel underneath it will be inverted. I only need 1 bit invertion though, if that matters. This must be done efficiently and it must work for every drawing function such as lines and polygons. I cant loop through the pixels afterwards because that would be overkill since the images are large and I know looping million pixels (thousands of times) on PHP GDLib is quite slow.

If PHP GDLib cant do this, are there some extensions to PHP that could do it? And if not, what else could I use without executing binary files on my server?

Here is example what im trying to achieve:
[image]

There are two rectangles drawn which will intersect at middle.